# Performance Angular 2 is low - test

Tags: angular

I developed this little system here using angular 2.
I lodge in amazon and I am finding it very slow. 
my system:

http://www.renatodev.com.br/

login: demo
senha: demo123

is normal this performance?

Comment: What do you mean by `very slow`, what exactly is slow? For me the UI runs smooth

Comment: It is likely to be my internet provider here. here is delay of 3 the 5 secounds. I'll check tomorrow at work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm worried that your issue is related to your code base. You're using AdminLTE, but please keep in mind that if you're looking for performance, you should try to recode your panel's scripts to Angular 2.

Currently, you have 180 page requests on initial loading, most of these are jQuery plugins for AdminLTE.

Take a look here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html 
Remember that these steps are only for production ready project.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I will analyze my code